# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.catalog_product_entity_integer' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2

I created custom product attributes in custom module. when Add new product is clicked it shows this error message.

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2_dev.catalog_product_entity_integer' doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have set `integer` as the `backend_type` or `type` property of your attribute. This is not possible. Normally you would use `varchar`, if you want to store numbers, use `int` or `decimal` if you want to store prices or weight.

You can find the types mentioned in the table `eav_attribute`.

**UPDATE**

While you are totally correct that you prefer class constants over strings, imho this does not apply here.

`\Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER` should be used when you create or modify columns of a database table. This is not the case, though, when you create a product attribute. This does not change any table structure, but only adds a new row to `eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute`.

If you look, for example, into `\Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup`, you will find that even here the `type` attribute is written as the string "int". So, I guess it's totally fine if you do it like this in your own module.

Comment: i am defining my type as :    'type'  => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,    for dropdown. whats wrong with this ?

Comment: I updated the answer